# How to use BeautifulSoup to extract data outside of html tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and SO. Here is my question.

I'm trying to extract data from the following webpage [NDBC - Station 46011.](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/46011.rss) I've been watching a tutorial on how to use BeautifulSoup to gather data from a webpage and I have the following code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/46011.rss'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
data_types = soup.find_all('strong')
for item in data_types:
    print(item.text)
```

This gives me the different data types (Wind direction, speed, gust, etc.). However, I am having trouble extracting the numerical data from this webpage. When you view the webpage source you can see that the numerical data is after the 'strong' tag and before the 'br' tag. Since it is not explicitly in between two tags I am having trouble extracting this data.

Thank you for all help in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8220732/3001761?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/46011.rss'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
data_types = soup.find_all("description")[1].text.split('\n')
for item in data_types:
    print(item)

Out[1]:
September 28, 2014 12:50 am PDT
Location: 35N 120.992W
Wind Direction: NW (320°)
Wind Speed: 7.8 knots
Wind Gust: 9.7 knots
Significant Wave Height: 8.5 ft
Dominant Wave Period: 9 sec
Average Period: 6.7 sec
Mean Wave Direction: NW (304°) 
Atmospheric Pressure: 29.90 in (1012.5 mb)
Pressure Tendency: +0.00 in (+0.0 mb)
Air Temperature: 62.1°F (16.7°C)
Water Temperature: 59.9°F (15.5°C)
```

Hope that helps :-)

Let me know if you need further steps as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want text (that's not inside a tag) next to each `<strong>` tag (and you're sure that there's always some text after `<strong>`), you could manipulate BeautifulSoup's `contents` list. The code below gives you both the label and content of the data items in a list of tuples.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/46011.rss'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
contents = soup.find_all('description')[1].contents
data=[]
for i,content in enumerate(contents):
    if content.name=="strong":
        data.append((content.string,contents[i+1].string))
print data
```

Output:

```
[(u'Location:', u' 35N 120.992W'), (u'Wind Direction:', u' NW (320\xb0)'), (u'Wind Speed:', u' 7.8 knots'), (u'Wind Gust:', u' 9.7 knots'), (u'Significant Wave Height:', u' 8.5 ft'), (u'Dominant Wave Period:', u' 9 sec'), (u'Average Period:', u' 6.7 sec'), (u'Mean Wave Direction:', u' NW (304\xb0) '), (u'Atmospheric Pressure:', u' 29.90 in (1012.5 mb)'), (u'Pressure Tendency:', u' +0.00 in (+0.0 mb)'), (u'Air Temperature:', u' 62.1\xb0F (16.7\xb0C)'), (u'Water Temperature:', u' 59.9\xb0F (15.5\xb0C)')]
```