# How to parse rss using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have this rss: http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?cat=190&feed=rss2 .

How can I get this value:

```
<div class="title">מצרכים:</div>
```

From this RSS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >

<channel>
    <title>בריא &#8211; Tnuva Bot</title>
    <atom:link href="http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?cat=190&#038;feed=rss2" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot</link>
    <description>Just another WordPress site</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 03 Aug 2016 08:56:16 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.5.3</generator>
    <item>
        <title>עוגת גבינה דיאטטית</title>
        <link>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1774</link>
        <comments>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1774#respond</comments>
        <pubDate>Tue, 26 Jul 2016 10:39:41 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[Tnuva Bot]]></dc:creator>
                <category><![CDATA[בריא]]></category>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1774</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[מספר מנות: תבנית מרובעת בגודל 20X20 ס&#8221;מ  &#124;  סיווג כשרות: מתכון חלבי  &#124;  מקור מתכון: מתכון: יעל גרטי; סטיילינג: אינה גוטמן; צילום: גל בן זאב  &#124;  זמן עבודה: 10 דקות  &#124;  מיומנות: קל מצרכים: 4 ביצים גדולות 5 כפות (60 גרם) סוכר 500 גרם גבינה לבנה 5% &#8220;תנובה&#8221; 50 גרם (5 כפות) קמח לבן (רגיל) לשידרוג: כפית קליפת לימון מגוררת או כפית תמצית וניל עוגת גבינה דיאטטית &#8211; &#8230; <a href="http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1774" class="more-link">Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "עוגת גבינה דיאטטית"</span></a>]]></description>
                <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><span class="prop_title">מספר מנות: </span><span class="prop_text">תבנית מרובעת בגודל 20X20 ס&#8221;מ</span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">סיווג כשרות: </span><span class="prop_text">מתכון חלבי</span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">מקור מתכון: </span><span class="prop_text">מתכון: יעל גרטי; סטיילינג: אינה גוטמן; צילום: גל בן זאב</span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">זמן עבודה: </span><span class="prop_text"><time datetime="PT10M">10 דקות</time></span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">מיומנות: </span><span class="prop_text">קל</span></p>
<div class="title">מצרכים:</div>
<div class="bottom10px right5px;">4 ביצים גדולות</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
<p>5 כפות (60 גרם) סוכר</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
<p>500 גרם גבינה לבנה 5% &#8220;תנובה&#8221;</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
<p>50 גרם (5 כפות) קמח לבן (רגיל)</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
<p>לשידרוג: כפית קליפת לימון מגוררת או כפית תמצית וניל</p></div>
<h3 class="title">עוגת גבינה דיאטטית &#8211; אופן הכנה:</h3>
<div class="text14 right5px">1. מחממים תנור ל-160 מעלות (בתוכנית טורבו) ומשמנים תבנית במעט חמאה מומסת או שמן קנולה.<br />
2. מפרידים ביצים. בקערה קטנה מערבבים גבינה לבנה, חלמונים וקליפת לימון (או תמצית וניל).<br />
3. שמים חלבונים במיקסר עם וו הקצפה ומקציפים במהירות גבוהה מאוד במשך דקה או עד שמתחיל להווצר קצף לבן. מוסיפים בהדרגה סוכר ומקציפים דקה, עד לקבלת קצף תפוח מאוד.<br />
4. מוסיפים את תערובת הגבינה הלבנה לקצף החלבונים ומערבלים במהירות איטית עד לאיחוד. עוצרים את פעולת המיקסר, אוספים בעזרת מרית את שניתז לדופנות ומערבלים שוב, לאיחוד – ולא מעבר לכך.<br />
5. מוסיפים את הקמח ומקציפים באיטיות עד להיטמעות הקמח ולא מעבר לכך. עוצרים את פעולת המיקסר, אוספים בעזרת מרית את שניתז לדופנות ומערבלים שוב, לאיחוד – ולא מעבר לכך. יוצקים את העיסה לתבנית המשומנת ומיישרים בעזרת מרית. כשהתנור חם, מכניסים את התבנית למרכזו ואופים במשך 38-40 דקות או עד להתייצבות והזהבה יפה. מוציאים, מצננים שעה בטמפ&#8217; החדר ועוד 3 שעות במקרר לפני ההגשה. מגישים קר.</div>
]]></content:encoded>
            <wfw:commentRss>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?feed=rss2&#038;p=1774</wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
        </item>
        <item>
        <title>עוגת מעדן יולו שוקולד מריר</title>
        <link>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1770</link>
        <comments>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1770#respond</comments>
        <pubDate>Tue, 26 Jul 2016 10:37:44 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[Tnuva Bot]]></dc:creator>
                <category><![CDATA[בריא]]></category>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1770</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[מספר מנות: תבנית אינגליש באורך 30 ס&#8221;מ – לא חד פעמית &#8211; או ל-16-23 מאפינס קטנים-בינוניים   &#124;  סיווג כשרות: מתכון חלבי  &#124;  מקור מתכון: מתכון: יעל גרטי; סטיילינג: אינה גוטמן; צילום: גל בן זאב  &#124;  זמן עבודה: 10 דקות  &#124;  מיומנות: קל מצרכים: 3 ביצים גדולות 180 גרם (כוס פחות 1-2 כפות) סוכר 3 גביעי &#8220;יולו&#8221; שוקולד מריר (123 גרם כל גביע) של &#8220;תנובה&#8221; 2 כפות שמן &#8230; <a href="http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1770" class="more-link">Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "עוגת מעדן יולו שוקולד מריר"</span></a>]]></description>
                <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><span class="prop_title">מספר מנות: </span><span class="prop_text">תבנית אינגליש באורך 30 ס&#8221;מ – לא חד פעמית &#8211; או ל-16-23 מאפינס קטנים-בינוניים </span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">סיווג כשרות: </span><span class="prop_text">מתכון חלבי</span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">מקור מתכון: </span><span class="prop_text">מתכון: יעל גרטי; סטיילינג: אינה גוטמן; צילום: גל בן זאב</span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">זמן עבודה: </span><span class="prop_text"><time datetime="PT10M">10 דקות</time></span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">מיומנות: </span><span class="prop_text">קל</span></p>
<div class="title">מצרכים:</div>
<div class="bottom10px right5px;">
<p>3 ביצים גדולות</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
<p>180 גרם (כוס פחות 1-2 כפות) סוכר</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
<p>3 גביעי &#8220;יולו&#8221; שוקולד מריר (123 גרם כל גביע) של &#8220;תנובה&#8221;</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
<p>2 כפות שמן קנולה (או שמן צמחי נטרלי אחר)</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
<p>220 גרם (כוס וחצי ועוד כף) קמח תופח</p>
<div class="sep-ingredients"></div>
</div>
<h3 class="title">עוגת מעדן יולו שוקולד מריר &#8211; אופן הכנה:</h3>
<div class="text14 right5px">1. מחממים תנור ל-170 מעלות ומשמנים תבנית אינגליש (לא חד-פעמית) באורך 30 ס&#8221;מ (או את השקעים בשתי תבניות מאפינס מסיליקון) במעט שמן קנולה.<br />
2. בקערה בינונית-גדולה טורפים ביצים וסוכר במטרף ידני עד לאיחוד והשגת מעט נפח.<br />
3. מוסיפים 3 גביעי &#8220;יולו&#8221; שוקולד מריר ושמן קנולה וטורפים לאיחוד.<br />
4. מוסיפים קמח תופח וטורפים לאיחוד – ולא מעבר לכך. הימנעו מערבוב יתר. יוצקים לתבנית המשומנת. כשהתנור חם מכניסים למרכז התנור ואופים במשך 45 דקות (לתבנית אינגליש 30 ס&#8221;מ) או 15 דקות (למאפינס בגודל קטן-בינוני). מוציאים, מצננים כשעה ומגישים.</div>
]]></content:encoded>
            <wfw:commentRss>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?feed=rss2&#038;p=1770</wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
        </item>
        <item>
        <title>קעריות שוקולד ממולאות מוס פטל</title>
        <link>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1767</link>
        <comments>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1767#respond</comments>
        <pubDate>Tue, 26 Jul 2016 10:35:48 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[Tnuva Bot]]></dc:creator>
                <category><![CDATA[בריא]]></category>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1767</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[מספר מנות: 6 קעריות  &#124;  סיווג כשרות: מתכון חלבי  &#124;  מקור מתכון: מתכון: יעל גרטי; סטיילינג: אינה גוטמן; צילום: גל בן זאב  &#124;  זמן עבודה: 15 דקות  &#124;  מיומנות: קל מצרכים: אם רוצים מוס ריבת חלב במקום מוס פטל מוסיפים לקצפת 2 כפות גדושות ריבת חלב (50-60 גרם). אם משתמשים בשוקולד 70% מוצקי קקאו, מומלץ להוסיף לו 1-2 כפות אבקת סוכר לפני ההמסה, כדי שהתוצאה לא תהיה מרירה &#8230; <a href="http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?p=1767" class="more-link">Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "קעריות שוקולד ממולאות מוס פטל"</span></a>]]></description>
                <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><span class="prop_title">מספר מנות: </span><span class="prop_text">6 קעריות</span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">סיווג כשרות: </span><span class="prop_text">מתכון חלבי</span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">מקור מתכון: </span><span class="prop_text">מתכון: יעל גרטי; סטיילינג: אינה גוטמן; צילום: גל בן זאב</span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">זמן עבודה: </span><span class="prop_text"><time datetime="PT15M">15 דקות</time></span><span class="prop_text1">  |  </span><span class="prop_title">מיומנות: </span><span class="prop_text">קל</span></p>
<div class="title">מצרכים:</div>
<div class="bottom10px right5px;">אם רוצים מוס ריבת חלב במקום מוס פטל מוסיפים לקצפת 2 כפות גדושות ריבת חלב (50-60 גרם). אם משתמשים בשוקולד 70% מוצקי קקאו, מומלץ להוסיף לו 1-2 כפות אבקת סוכר לפני ההמסה, כדי שהתוצאה לא תהיה מרירה מדי</div>
<h3 class="title">קעריות שוקולד ממולאות מוס פטל &#8211; אופן הכנה:</h3>
<div class="text14 right5px">1. שמים בקערית חסינת-חום שוקולד מריר. מכניסים למיקרוגל, מפעילים למשך 30 שניות, מוציאים, מערבבים וכך שוב עוד פעמיים-שלוש או עד לקבלת נוזל חלק ואחיד, ללא גושים. מושחים מיד את השקעים בתבנית מאפינס בגודל בינוני מסיליקון, כך שמצפים לגמרי את תוכן השקעים בשוקולד. מוודאים שהשקעים מלאים שוקולד ושלא נותרו חורים. מכניסים למקפיא למשך 10 דקות. כעבור 10 דקות מוציאים את התבנית מהמקפיא, מחלצים את קעריות השוקולד מהתבנית ומעבירים לצלחת הגשה או מגש. מאחסנים במקפיא או במקרר עד להמשך. שימו לב שלא להרבות במגע ידני עם גביעי השוקולד.<br />
2. מקציפים שמנת מתוקה וכף סוכר במיקסר עם וו הקצפה במהירות הגבוהה ביותר, במשך דקה וחצי עד שתי דקות, עד לקבלת קצפת יפה.<br />
3. מוסיפים 2 כפות ריבת פטל לקצפת ומערבלים במהירות נמוכה לאיחוד. משחררים מהמיקסר, מערבבים במרית ויוצקים 1-2 כפות מהקצפת הוורודה לכל קערית שוקולד (להגשה יפה מעבירים את הקצפת הוורודה לשק זילוף עם צנתר משונן ומזלפים לגביעי השוקולד). מאחסנים כחצי שעה (עד ארבע שעות) במקרר או 40-50 דקות במקפיא לפני ההגשה.</div>
]]></content:encoded>
            <wfw:commentRss>http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?feed=rss2&#038;p=1767</wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: It would be better to post the rss directly  in your post.  It is impossible to read as a picture. Show any etree code you have tried.   What tag are you looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse all item elements with children from RSS feed with beautifulsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220732/parse-all-item-elements-with-children-from-rss-feed-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: You're going to want to get the `<description>` contents and parse out the CDATA contents. From there you'll need to be careful which character decoding you're using as this obviously contains special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want, all you need is a simple select using *lxml* or *html5lib* as the parser:

```
In [6]: import requests

In [7]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [8]: url = "http://socialminisite.com/tnuvabot/?cat=190&feed=rss2"

In [9]:  soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,"lxml")

In [10]: print(soup.select_one("div.title"))
<div class="title">מצרכים:</div>
```